# Sails Js : remove unsafe chars from URL using route.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js, url-routing

Problem Statement :

1. I have pushed my custom url sitemap to google, Google crawler indexed those urls but problem is with the URL which i have pushed contains some unsafe & url reserved chars, when user click on the URL my sails server throw errors:

For example : i have a url : http://www.example.com/.html
 is like url_slug + unique identifier => my-college-best-faculty-111109.html

Note : my page is render by unique identifier but due to url unsafe chars my page either throw error or render 404 page.

Please suggest me some best practices,

when user click on link which indexed in google search, my routes.js redirect to 301 to the url which we create after removal of unsafe chars.